# Universal Database Backup / Extract Format

Tags: database, backup, extract

does there exist a universal database backup/extract format?

I'll explain where I'm coming from: our application supports several database vendors, DB2, MsSql, MySql and Oracle. Currently when we request a backup from a customer they must make a full backup in the vendor specific format.

We have a small but powerful homegrown utility which allows us to import and export fully or partially from any database vendor. Unfortunately the common extract format is dBase tables which does not work very well as we are now using SQL field types that are not supported.

The solution is to use an existing industry standard backup/extract format, if one exists. While I don't mind inventing my own format an industry standard format would have more possiblities.

Does one exist or will I have to invent one?

Thanks in advance,

Stephen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only universal export format is some variation on the theme of a text dump.

There are multiple possible formats - fixed or delimited (or separated).
When delimited, it can be CSV or some other related format.
Escape conventions, especially for embedded newlines, tend to be idiosyncratic.

Another tricky part is how the different DBMS prefer to encode things like binary data BLOB values - Base64, hex, ...and probably some others...

XML is also a possibility, but there is no standardization on which XML schema or DTD to use.

Comment: I understand the difficulty with non-standard field types. Luckily, we only use a common subset, for the moment. 

XML would appear to be the ideal choice until you consider that some of the databases exceed 20 Gb. XML would add a lot of overhead unless compression is used and event then....?

Answer (score 1):

FYI: In the end I settled on using SQLite as our format. There we several reasons for this:

1. Uses a single file which is very handy for transport.
2. Supports all of the field types that we require.
3. Has support for many platforms and languages.
4. Is open-source and free.
5. Small footprint.
6. Very fast for appending records.
7. Our applications can talk directly to SQLite databases.

Number 7 was definitely the clincher as when we recover a backup (or extract) from a customer we do not have to restore it but can just connect to it directly.

Answer (score 0):

How about XML?  CSV?

Comment: I would have to decide on the format in this case, so I would consider that a homegrown format. Also, as below, what about compression.

Comment: @Steve: You asked about industry standards for doing this. XML and CSV are it.

Comment: Thats pretty much as I understood it. So even though XML and CSV are industry standards there is no industry standard to describe how you might store a full database backup in it. If I used XML I would have to decide on how to organise the data within the XML file rather than a standard way. What I would really like is a situation whereby I have a backup file (backup.xyz) which I can import/restore into any database in a similar way that MsSQl can restore a .bak file

Answer (score 0):

All the DBMS I know of (including all the ones you've listed) support exporting and importing to [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

For bonus points, [compress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression#Lossless_data_compression) the exports to save space.

Comment: Compression is definitely a must, if only to have the option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to look for a tool who can pump data.

One example here : http://www.clevercomponents.com/products/datapump/ibdatapump.asp

It will not specifically fit your need but may be it is the way to go.

Comment: I downloaded it and tried to run it, but unfortunately it does not run without Interbase installed. However, it would appear that IBPump copies data directly from the source to the destination without passing through an intermediary format. We would need an intermediary format as it is rare that the source and destination databases are on the same network. Sometimes the customer databases are so big that an external HD and a courrier is required as an over the internet transfer would take too long.